# Domain modelling with Repository in a 3-tier pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, 3-tier

Please note that this code is a code example of how I usually write my code but I have just removed code that would remove focus from my question. I look forward to listen.

I can understand that I need atleast 10 reps. before I can post images and my images illustrates my question... So please follow this link to see my original question at codereview.stackexchange.com - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44237/domain-modelling-with-repository

I've been struggling with some architectural problems which I'm having a hard time figuring out myself.

Im trying to construct a basic structure of a project with the domain model and repository pattern.

It's easy enough to construct the POCO classes and repository when I want to implement some Business logic and different kinds of UI (i.ex. WinForms and MVC) I feel that I miss something because I feel that my code is tightly coupled and I always have to reffer to the POCO classes when ever I need to get an object and show it.

I start out by constructing the following projects in C#(vs2012):

Model

DAL

BL

TestConsole

Here is an example of my Model a model Class:

```
namespace Panda.Model
{
    public class Person : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {

        }
        public Person(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example code from my Persons class in my BL project:

```
using Panda.DAL.Repositories;
using Panda.DAL.Contexts;
using Panda.Model;
namespace Panda.BL
{
    public class Logic
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Person> _personRep;
        public Logic()
        {
            _personRep = new Repository<Person>(new GenericContext());
        }

        public LinkedList<Person> ListOfPersons()
        {
            LinkedList<Person> persons = new LinkedList<Person>();
            persons.AddFirst(new Person("Nicklas"));
            persons.AddFirst(new Person("Martin"));
            persons.AddFirst( new Person("Kresten"));
            return persons;
        }
    }
```

My DAL project consists of generic Repositories that takes a Class of type IEntity:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The Generic Repository class that can use all Model classes when istantiating it.
        /// It holds all the generic methods for insert, select, delete and update.
        /// </summary>
        internal DbSet<T> DbSet;
        internal GenericContext Context;
        public Repository(GenericContext context)
        {
            this.Context = context;
            DbSet = context.Set<T>();
        }
```

My code for the program.cs file in the Console app looks like this:

```
using Panda.BL;

namespace Panda.TestConsole
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Logic lol = new Logic();

            foreach (var item in lol.ListOfPersons())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that I don't know how to decouple my Model and DAL further from my UI project (Console etc..) Everytime I want to get i.ex. a Person object I have to of course to reference to my Model project from my console project when ever I want to use a method from the BL project.

My understanding of the whole DDD and 3 tier pattern is that you should be able only talk (reference) to the BL when ever you want to add a new UI project (i.ex. Console, WebForms or MVC) But now I always have to reference to both Models and BL when ever I want to use a method in the BL project.

Right now I feel like have alot of depencies which coupling things to tightly..

I really look forward to hear your thoughts on this which has been puzzling me for a while.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I am also writing some 3-tier application as a training for my skills. I also created a project structure as you: BLL, DAL, Model, UI (an MVC project) and Tests layer. From my experience I know that your e.g. main application (in my case the UI layer with MVC project) should have reference to BLL and Model only! You should not add reference to DAL. The BLL should make use of Model and DAL. In the end the DAL should only reference to the Model. That's it.

BTW, you should avoid this:

```
public class Logic {
    private readonly IRepository<Person> _personRep;
    public Logic()
    {
        _personRep = new Repository<Person>(new GenericContext());
    }
}
```

Instead make use of dependency injection:

```
public class Logic {
    private readonly IRepository<Person> _personRep;
    public Logic(IRepository<Person> personRep)
    {
        _personRep = personRep;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on my code.

It makes sense but then how do I name my classes in the BL? Do I have a class for foreach Model object in my Model (Model.Person <--> BL.Person). what is the naming conventions here? Do I have just one class that takes care of all Model objects?

Comment: You are welcome. For more details you could visit pluralsight website. They have this architecture module in their library and there is a special course about n-tier applications. It's really helpful! 

I will tell you how I am doing things in my application. 

1st - I have a Model.Category (Domain)
2nd - I Have a Repository.CategoryRepository (DAL)
3rd - I have a BusinessLogic.CategoryLogic (BLL)

Model is obvious. In CategoryRepository I am accessing database and retrieving mapped objects. Then in my CategoryLogic I do some logic that i need to use later in my MVC application.

Comment: I found something that may be useful to you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-En - I am gonna read it too:)

Comment: That link is the far best explaination of the Rep and N-tier model.

Answer (score 0):

To decouple UI I use a DataTransferObject pattern so that my services layer or BAL is the only layer then using Domain and Repository.

DTO's are just poco that only contain the information for the object your are transmitting and that is it, nothing more.

To map data from domain object to dto I then use AutoMapper (a god send)

Your UI layer whatever it may be will then only ever deal with dto's relevant to the work being done at that point in time. Whether it be from a Web Services layer or the service library itself.

**Domain Layer**

Altered your sample above to show how it works a bit better and added concurrency field to show how to handle that also with the dto's and when its needed.

```
public class Person : IEntity
{
    [key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public Person() { }

    public Person(string firstName, string surname)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        Surname = surname;
    }
}
```

**DTO Layer**

In one namespace for easier viewing, i usually separate every dto class into its own file as per normal, and also create folders to store relevant dto in. ie. CreatePersonDto will go in the Create folder along with all other Create Dto's, ListPersonDto in the List folder, QueryPersonDto in the Query fodler within the project, adds extra using references to your class files but that's nothing.

```
namespace Panda.DataTransferObjects
{
    public class PersonDto
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }

    public class CreatePersonDto
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }


    public class EditPersonDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }


        // user context info, i would usually use a separate ServiceContextDto to do
        // this, if you need to store whom changed what and when, and how etc 
        // ie. log other information of whats going on and by whom.
        // Needed in Create and Edit DTO's only
        public string ChangedBy { get; set; }
    }

    public class ListPersonDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class QueryPersonDto
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }

}
```

**BAL  or Services Layer**

Add to your stuff above

Firstly a Create person method. You UI layer will create a dto setup the info and call the create method below. Create dto's do not need to contain Id, timestamp (rowversion) for concurrency etc, as none of that information is needed when creating a new object all you need is the members of the object that can be added by the repo. In this example FirstName and Surname only. Other data like user context data etc could also be passed through within these objects, but you don't need anything else.

```
        public int CreatePerson(CreatePersonDto dto)
        {
            //checks to ensure dto is valid

            var instance = new Person(dto.FirstName, dto.Surname);                                

            // do your stuff to persist your instance of person. ie. save it

            return instance.Id;
        }
```

Secondly a Get of the Person instance. You pass it the id of the person instance your after and it retrieves it and returns a PersonDto. Firstly you need to obtain your Person object from the persistence layer via your repository, then you need to convert that object to the Dto for return to the client. For the mapping i use AutoMapper, it will help enormously with this type of pattern, your doing a lot of mapping from one object to another and that is what it is for.

```
        public PersonDto Get(int id) {
             Person instance = // repo stuff to get person from store/db

             //Manual way to map data from one object to the other.
             var personDto = new PersonDto();
             personDto.Id = instance.Id;
             personDto.FirstName = instance.firstName;
             personDto.Surname = instance.Surname;
             personDto.RowVersion = instance.RowVersion;

             return personDto;


             // As mentioned I use AutoMapper for this, so the above becomes a 1 liner.
             // **Beware** there is some configuration for this to work in this case you
             // would have the following in a separate automapper config class.
             // AutoMapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>();
             // Using AutoMapper all the above 6 lines done for you in this 1.
             return Mapper.Map<Person, PersonDto>(instance);
        }
```

**ListPersonDto**

As previously stated use AutoMapper for this and things like object conversion in a query becomes painless.

```
        public IEnumerable<ListPersonDto> ListOfPersons(QueryPersonDto dto = null)
        {
            // check dto and setup and querying needed
            // i wont go into that

            // Using link object mapping from the Person to ListPersonDto is even easier
            var listOfPersons = _personRep.Where(p => p.Surname == dto.Surname).Select(Mapper.Map<Person, ListPersonDto>).ToList();

            return listOfPersons;
        }
```

Just for completeness the automapper signature for the above would look something like the following, considering ListPersonDto only contains name.

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Person, ListPersonDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => { return string.Format("{0} {1}", src.FirstName, src.Surname); } ))
```

So your app will then need to only see the BAL & dto layer.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Logic lol = new Logic();

        CreatePersonDto dto = new CreatePersonDto { FirstName = "Joe", Surname = "Bloggs" };
        var newPersonId = lol.Create(dto);

        foreach (var item in lol.ListOfPersons())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }

        //or to narrow down list of people
        QueryPersonDto queryDto = new QueryPersonDto { Surname = "Bloggs" }

        foreach (var item in lol.ListOfPersons(queryDto))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

It adds extra work, but unfortunately there is no easy way to do it, and using a pattern like above will help separate things and make it easier to track down issues. Your dto should only ever have whats necessary for the operation, so it make it easier to see where things are left out or not included. AutoMapper is a must have for this scenario, it makes life much easier, and reduces your typing, there are plenty good examples of using automapper around.

Hope this helps in getting closer to a solution.

Comment: Hey Mark,
Thanks for extensive example of decoupling UI further. I thought about using the DTO POCO classes too but ended up gettting confusing code but your solution looks great and I will experiment with it. Thanks again for a very nice explaination!

Comment: No problem, just remeber to keep the dto's simple for the 1 purpose, and it keeps it simple. 1 thing i didn't mention above is for updates.  If you display data, like a details view, then use the PersonDto to populate your form or display, but then use the EditPersonDto when you send it back. Even though the 2 dto's are similar this way you keep each dto for the purpose at hand and it help simplify knowing what should be used and when. Unfortunately there is no definitive guide out there to show a proper multi-tier implementation, and its not simple and gets confusing at times. good luck